# Ajax call being fired multiple times [React]

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ajax

I have a function that makes a request to the server for an array of data. I have made sure that this function is only being called once by logging a message to the console every time it's called.

Despite this, it always returns multiple (2-6) identical arrays. Here's my code... It is all inside the render() function.

```js
function renderTopics() {
  console.log("Calling renderTopics")
  self.setState({
    doneTopicRender: true
  })
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8009/api/data/topicQuery",
    // async: false
  })
    .done(function (data) {
    return console.log(data)
  })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
    console.log("[Error] AJAX Request failed")
  })
}

function RenderSelect() {
  console.log(self.state.doneTopicRender)
  if (!self.state.doneTopicRender) {
    renderTopics()
  }
  return (
    <div>Some Content</div>
  )
}

if (this.state.userData) {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.userData.firstLogin
        ? <RenderSelect />
        : <RenderHome />
      }
    </div>
  )
} else {
  return (
    <h1>Loading</h1>
  )
}
```

Here is state

```
state = {
    userData: undefined,
    compData: undefined,
    doneTopicRender: false
}
```

And here's the console
[Screenshot of POST requests made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dH6L.png)

Comment: I think we need more code context. Where is your react component that uses RenderSelect? Also, why are they called `render..` -- they don't render anything, nor do they even return anything or set state variables..

Comment: I've updated the snippet with come more context. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is that your functions are inside the render funcation, which is called repeatedly of course. So your helper functions get re-defined. Try moving them out into the component.

Comment: It could be good to have an html/js snippet example to test it! thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't the if statement that runs before calling renderTopics stop this from happening?